# My script doesn't read my prefabs

Tags: unity, c#

My script is supposed to randomly spawn different slipper projectiles from an array, but when I hit Play Mode, my filled prefabs disappear from the script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnSlippers : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] slipperArray;
float randX;
Vector2 spawningArea;
public float spawnRate = 2f;
float nextSpawn = 0.0f;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    slipperArray = new GameObject[6];

        if (Time.time > nextSpawn)
        {
            nextSpawn = Time.time + spawnRate;
            randX = Random.Range(-12.47f, 10.4f);
            spawningArea = new Vector2(randX, transform.position.y);
            Instantiate(slipperArray[Random.Range(0, slipperArray.Length)], spawningArea, Quaternion.identity);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
slipperArray = new GameObject[6];
```

This line says "please throw out whatever was previously in the `slipperArray` variable, and replace it with a freshly-allocated empty array"

If that's not the behaviour you want, don't ask for it. Delete that line.